# Gradle - how to exclude a specific package from deploy?

Tags: gradle

I have 2 environments - staging and production, i would like to include in the staging environment a package that must not reach the production environment .

I would like to create two different tasks (one for the production, the other is for the staging.) 
one of them will call the "war" task with the exclusion of the package (production) the other will call the "war" task with the inclusion of the package(staging)

how can i do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code may help You. In general You can create various configurations and then build a jar or other artifact based on these custom configurations (dependencies added to them):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
   a
   b
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   a 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
   b 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1' 
}

task prod(type: Jar) {
   from configurations.a
}

task staging(type: Jar) {
   from configurations.b
}
```